# Modifying two aggregates in a single transaction (DDD)

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design

I have this simple domain model. The user performs an activity, which has duration and distance. To each activity, there can be assigned a gear item(s) used (shoes for running). After the assignment, the duration and distance are added to the totals on the gear item.

Both Activity and GearItem are aggregate roots. When I assign an item to an activity, I need to add item's id to the activity and update totals on the item.

How to orchestrate this operation?

1. Call `GearItem.AssignUsage()` directly from `Activity.AddItem()`?
2. Do it in an app service in a single transaction, calling `GearItem.AssignUsage()` just after `Activity.AddItem()` (it breaks the rule of one transaction per AR).
3. Use domain event (Udi Dahan's static class) - but how and where to avoid single transaction problem?
4. Or something else, much better?

*GearItem AR, contains totals from Activities:*

```
public class GearItem: Entity<GearItem>
{
  ...
 public Usage AssignedUsage { get; private set; };

  public void AssignUsage(Activity activity)
  {
    AssignedUsage = new Usage(AssignedUsage.Time + activity.Time, 
    AssignedUsage.Distance + activity.Distance, AssignedUsage.Uses + 1);
  }    
}
```

*Activity AR, contains IDs of assigned GearItems:*

```
public class Activity: Entity<Activity>
{
  ...
  private List<int> items = new List<int>(); 
  public TimeSpan Time { get; }
  public double Distance { get; }

  public bool AddItem(GearItem item)
  {
    if (items.Contains(item.Id)) return false;

    items.Add(item.Id);
    return true;
  }
}
```

*Usage value object:*

```
public class Usage: ValueObject<Usage>
{
  ...
  public TimeSpan Time { get; private set; }
  public double Distance { get; private set; }
  public int Uses { get; private set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should resist the temptation to modify two aggregates in a single transaction. There are two rules that help you to not do that:

1. Reference Other Aggregates Only by Their ID
2. Use Eventual Consistency Outside the Boundary

So, in order to update the `AssignedUsage` for a `GearItem` you will use eventual consistency.

You could do that using domain events or by periodically calculating the usages for all `GearItems`.

**Using domain events:**

After a `GearItem` is assigned to an Activity, you publish a `GearItemAssignedToActivity` event that is caught by a `Process manager` that calls `GearItem.AssignUsage(Time,Distance)` in a new transaction (by first loading the GearItem using its ID from the Repository).

**Periodically updating the GearItem's usage**

In a cron/scheduled task/whatever you reset the usage to each `GearItem`, then load every `Activity` and load and call `GearItem.AssignUsage(Time,Distance)` for each assigned `GearItem`.

Also, I suggest that you decouple the two aggregates and do not pass references to method calls. For example, you should not pass the entire Activity aggregate to the `GearItem.AssignUsage` method, but only the required properties. In this way a `GearItem` must not know or depend on the entire `Activity`.